eager_load と preload で同じ関連を指定した場合の挙動
以下のように、eaer_loadとpreloadに同じ関連を指定したとします。
groups = HogeGroup.eager_load(:fugas)
                  .order('fugas.sort_num desc')
                  .preload(fugas: [:aaaa, :bbbb])

この時groups[0].fugasで取得できるデータはeager_loadとpreloadどちらのものになりますか？
実際に試してみたところ、ソートされていたのでeager_loadの方で取得されたデータのようなのですが、場合によるのか、eager_loadが採用されるのが仕様なのか知りたいと思います。
